# Changing jTree layout in Java to (Right to Left), instead of default layout from (Left to Right)

Tags: jtree

Please help, I want to change the layout of the jTree layout from right to left(Arabic), I couldn't find any way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I moved to JavaFX and their TreeView solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I know that a long time has passed since this question was asked. I post the answer just in case someone needs that.

```
Component.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
```

will layout the JTree (and probably other swing components) from right to left.

(instead of Component just put the name of object you created from JTree class)